# Does Floyd Mayweather endorse a teeth whitening product?

Tags: advertising

An [advertorial for Snow teeth-whitening system](https://snow.dailywebtips.io/en/1/) contains images of former boxer [Flloyd Mayweather Jr](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floyd_Mayweather_Jr.) endorsing the product.

> Try Snow teeth whitening - it's the best thing money can buy. - Floyd Mayweather

(Other celebrities which they claim endorse their product include [Chuck Liddell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chuck_Liddell) and [Demi-Leigh Nel-Peters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Demi-Leigh_Nel-Peters))

Does Floyd Mayweather endorse this suspicious-looking product?

Comment: I'm not sure what to be skeptical about here.  Also why are you using tinyurl?

Comment: If you click on tiny url you can see a very long url

Comment: @user1898829: Typically we just hide the URL behind a link, so we don't need to rely on a third-party. In this case, most of the URL wasn't necessary and I simplified it.

Comment: Thank you for the info and updating it.

Answer (score 7):

This [tweet](https://twitter.com/FloydMayweather/status/1038268651491586049) from Mayweather's account, September 8, 2018 includes a video of him holding the product and talking directly to the camera about it, clearly endorsing the product, including the quote above.